# Multiple Joins in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm doing multiple joins in Mongo, but I'm not seeing the expected output. I suspect this is something down to project, but I'm I'm doing two joins back to back, should I need to explicitly use the $project command. The join works for either, but together I am missing the first join.

```
results = db['profiles'].aggregate([
    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'amounts', 
            'localField': 'id', 
            'foreignField': 'id', 
            'as': 'joinedAmounts',
            'pipeline': [
                {'$sort': {'date': -1}},
                {'$limit': 1}
                ]
        }
    },

    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'inv', 
            'localField': 'id', 
            'foreignField': 'id', 
            'as': 'joinedInv'
        }
        },
])
```

After which I am missing the the initial join.

Here are some example documents

**profiles**

```
{"name": "blah", "id": 12345}
```

**amounts**

```
{"id": 12345, "date": "11/11/22", "amount": 123.00}
```

**inv**

```
{"id": 12345, "date": "11/11/22", "value": 11.00}
```

Comment: Please provide some sample input data and desired result.

Comment: Your example seems to work perfectly fine in [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lSQ1gifnwtq)?

Comment: Why on earth do you store `Date` values as string? You should **never** do that, it's a design flaw. And even with 2-digit year, did you never hear about the [Year-2000 Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem)?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, I don't. Simply did this to illustrate the problem! I had to remove sensitive data!